# Show that $c \notin S $ but that $ n \in S, \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, n >c$ where $S$ is the following set

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers. Set $c=ab−a−b$ and define

$S = \left \{ n \in \mathbb{Z}\mid n = ax+by, x \geq  0, y \geq  0 \right \}$

Show that $ c \notin S$ but that $n \in S$ for all integers $n>c$

.
.

Any idea how to approach this question. I have rewritten c as products of a and b, I have considered c as $gcd(a,b)$ but I'm really getting nowhere.

Thanks for any help in advance and my apologies for the bad title.

Comment: From this definition looks like $S = \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Jihad I suppose it does, including the zero

Comment: I'm half-programmer.

Comment: I suppose x, y are natural numbers?

Comment: @Bernard, yes they are...any ideas?

Comment: Don't you need $a,b $ to be coprime? Otherwise, for example $a =2, b = 4, c = 2$, but $3 \notin S$.

Answer (score 1):

We do need to assume that $a,b$ are relatively prime. Then by the Chinese Remainder Theorem every integer $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ can be written as $n = ax+by$, for $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

So the question is asking you to show that $c=ab-a-b$ is the largest integer such that at least one of $x,y$ must be negative.

Again by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, if $n,a,b$ are fixed, $x$ is uniquely determined $\pmod{b}$ and $y$ is uniquely determined $\pmod{a}$. Also, if $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfy $ax+by=n$, then $x+b,y-a$ and $x-b,y+a$ also have the same property.

This allows us to write any number $n$ uniquely as $ax+by$, where $0 \leq x < b$. Then we claim that $n \in S$ if and only if, when written in this form, $y \geq 0$.

The "if" direction is easy. For the "only if" direction, suppose we have $ax+by=n$, with $0 \leq x < b$ and $y < 0$, and $ax'+by' = n$, for some other $x',y' \geq 0$. But $x' \geq x$, since $x' \geq 0$, $x < b$, and $x \equiv x' \pmod{b}$. And $y' > y$. So $ax'+by' > ax+by$, a contradiction.

So for $n \not \in S$, we have $n = ax+by$, with $x \leq b-1$ and $y \leq -1$, so certainly $c = a(b-1) -b \not \in S$, and $c$ is the largest integer $\not \in S$, as desired.